# How to sort columns left to right?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm trying to sort the columns, based on the values shown in a certain row.

The data consists of two tables, separated by an empty line.

```
      A       B       C       D       E
1           12QA03  12QA01  12QA02
2   Step 1  32      23      82
3   Step 2  43      92      1
4   Step 3  12      12      84
5   Step 4  65      89      51
6   
7           24QA93  24QA91  24QA95  24QA98
8   Step 1  94      77      83      28
9   Step 2  92      30      5       19
10  Step 3  19      82      16      49
11  Step 4  11      41      7       17
```

The goal is to get this:

```
      A       B       C       D       E
1           12QA01  12QA02  12QA03
2   Step 1  23      82      32
3   Step 2  92      1       43
4   Step 3  12      84      12
5   Step 4  89      51      65
6           
7           24QA91  24QA93  24QA95  24QA98
8   Step 1  77      94      83      28
9   Step 2  30      92      5       19
10  Step 3  82      19      16      49
11  Step 4  41      11      7       17
```

I have written a macro that works properly for the top table, but gives an error for the second:

```
Sub SortData()

    'Sort top table
    With Range("B1:D5")
    .Rows.Sort Key1:=.Rows.Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
    End With

    'Sort top table
    With Range("B7:E11")
    .Rows.Sort Key1:=.Rows.Range("B7"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
    End With

End Sub
```

What is going wrong? Or might there be a better method? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works.

```
Sub SortLTable()
    Range("B1:D5").Sort Key1:=Range("B1:D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
    Range("B7:E11").Sort Key1:=Range("B7:E7"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

A little simpler perhaps:

```
Sub SortLTable()
    Range("B7:E11").Sort Key1:=Range("B7:E7"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code a bit, but now it works!

Comment: Now I understand. I thought I mentioned that I wanted to sort both tables.

Answer (score 2):

Put something in A1 and A7 temporarily, such as "A", so that you have complete tables (with filled header columns). You can remove these values after sorting.

Your use of `With` and `Rows` is confusing the issue though:

```
Sub SortData()

    'Sort top table
    Range("A1,A7").Value = "A"
    Range("B1:D5").Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Orientation:=xlLeftToRight

    'Sort top table
    Range("B7:E11").Sort Key1:=Range("B7"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Orientation:=xlLeftToRight
    Range("A1,A7").Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Your suggestion works partially. The part where you place a temporary value in A1 and A7 removes the original values. Unfortunately, I need those values. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I was basing it on your sample which doesn't have anything in A1 or A7 ;). Anyway, glad you sorted.